# Piping commands together in unix

Tags: shell, pipe

How do I pipe the output of one command to another in unix? For example,
If I want to pipe the output of sort to tail, how would I do that?

Comment: downvoted because this seems to show very minimal research.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this :

```
sort file.txt | tail
```

See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html  and search *2.9.2 Pipelines* paragraph

Comment: Just that in this case `sort` has to finish doing its job before `tail` starts its. The idea is that the second in line gets to start working as soon as the first one gives it something to ork on.

Answer (score 3):

The `|` character is used to pipe the stdout of one program to the stdin of another.

```
sort file.txt | tail
```

This will work in any POSIX compliant shell.